# How to update a Cosmos DB document partition key element?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I need to update a document changing the value of the element being used as the partition key. The documentation says that a document is uniquely identified by its id and partition key.

So, if I change the partition key will this always create new document?
Or, will it only create a new document if it is placed on another partition?

If a new document is always created then I think the safest way to update is

1. Create new document.
2. If successful, delete old document.
3. Failure to delete will result in duplicate data but at least the data is not lost.

If a new document is not always created, how can I identify the cases where a new document was created so that I can delete the old one? I don't want to delete anything without having the new one created first since there is no transactional way to do this.

Regards All.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trying to update the partition key value will simply fail.
Trying to upsert the partition key value will create a new document with the same id in a different logical partition.

What the process should be is:

- Keep the old document in memory
- Delete the old document
- Create the new document
- If the later fails then recreate the old document

Cosmos DB doesn't support transactions so there is no way to do this otherwise, and you can't use a stored procedure as they only run against a single logical partition.

Comment: If every partition key value has a unique logical partition then it seems like I should be able to create the new document first and then delete the old one. I want to avoid any time where the data only exists in memory as a crash would cause the data to be lost.

Comment: yes you can create new document with same is and different partition key first and then delete the old one